# Frame Accurate Seeking in WebM

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, html5-video, webm

I'm trying to do a somewhat tricky thing with WebM. I am trying to encode a stack of 256 biological images as a WebM. The time dimension of motion is very similar to the space dimension of the image stack so the compression ratios are insanely good. However, I am having trouble decoding the movie frames. I know that WebM uses an IPB predictive coding scheme, but I was reading several blog posts and discussion groups from WHATWG from 2011, and they said that frame accurate seeking was working in Chrome at that time.

When I do `video.currentTime = 0`, I correctly get this:

[image: tissue slice at time zero]

However, if I do `video.currentTime = 0.34` (for example) I get something that looks like this:

[image]

It looks like I'm getting a random poorly predicted frame. Am I just encoding the video wrong? When I play it normally it looks fine.

I encoded the video using 256 pngs using ffmpeg compiled with libvpx using the VP8 codec.

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -start_number 0 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -qmin 10 -qmax 42 out.webm`

References to the WHATWG and some other info from 2011:

WHATWG discusses frame accuracy:

https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2011Jan/0372.html

BBC Tech Director talking about frame accuracy:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2011/02/frame_accurate_video_in_html5.html

Comment: Offhand, it looks like Chrome is naively decoding a P/B frame as if it was an I-frame. Run your webm generation command with `-g 1` inserted as an output switch and check.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mulvya! What does the -g flag do? I didn't see it in the man pages or help. I did some googling and it seems to be related to motion estimation, which makes sense based on what you're saying.

Comment: Ah finally found it. It's the max keyframe distance. Perfect! Thank you. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html I tried it with -g 1 and it worked perfectly, though it only compressed as much as jpg. Interesting to investigate. :)

Comment: I didn't mean that to be a solution, only for diagnosis. Whichever WebM decoder you;re using ought to be able to properly decode any random frame. Look into that.

Comment: Ah... well... I could use an asm.js decoder if that exists (it seems to for h264, broadway.js), but otherwise I'm kind of stuck with whatever Chrome (or other browsers) provide. Is there something else I could do if I know that it's doing poorly with P and B frames?

Comment: For working with native Chrome, experiment with higher g values till it still works. [Route9](http://badassjs.com/post/13551173773/route9js-a-vp8webm-decoder-in-javascript) seems to be a VP8 counterpart to Broadway.